# Exporting a pandas dataframe to excel using xlwings

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

```
import xlwings as xw
import pandas as pd
```

I'm trying to export a df into a specific sheet on excel I'm getting the following error:

```
self._oleobj_.Invoke(*(args + (value,) + defArgs))
TypeError: Objects for SAFEARRAYS must be sequences (of sequences), or a buffer object.
```

This is a simplified version of my DataFrame

```
df=pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'Color': ['red','blue','red','red','green','red','yellow'],
        'Type': ['Oil', 'Aluminium', 'Oil', 'Oil', 'Cement Paint', 'Synthetic Rubber', 'Emulsion'],
        'Finish' : ['Satin', 'Matte', 'Matte', 'Satin', 'Semi-gloss', 'Satin', 'Satin'],
        'Use' : ['Interior', 'Exterior', 'Interior', 'Interior', 'Exterior', 'Exterior', 'Exterior'],
        'Price' : [55, 75, 60, 60, 55, 75, 50]
    }
)
```

Here's  my code:

```
df = df.loc[(df['Price'] == 55) & (df['Color'] == 'red')]
df1 = df.loc[(df['Price'] == 55) & (df['Color'] == 'blue')]
df2 = df.loc[(df['Price'] == 55) & (df['Color'] == 'yellow') & (df['Color'] == 'green')]

# Load Wookbook
app = xw.App(visible = False)
wb = xw.Book(File_path)
Sheet1 = wb.sheets['Sheet1']
Sheet2 = wb.sheets['Sheet2']
Sheet3 = wb.sheets['Sheet3']

#Write data into Workbook 
Sheet1.range('A1').options(index=False, header=False ).value = df
Sheet2.range('A1').options(index=False, header=False ).value = df2
Sheet3.range('A1').options(index=False, header=False ).value = df2

#Save data in Workbook and close wb
LPLwb.save()
LPLwb.close()
LPLapp.quit()
```

The end goal is to be able to export the different dfs into the specific sheets. I've done this before with no issue, but now I'm getting an odd error I had never gotten before. Googled it for a while but found nothing.

Any direction would be highly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Hmm. Your sample code works for me. That looks like a `win32com` error.

Comment: Do I go File Explorer --> search bar --> `%temp%` --> gen_py --> 3.10 --> and delete pycache?